# mysql limit number of results for specific column

Tags: mysql

I have a complicated query I've been working on, and I recently changed one of the columns so that there will be multiple entries that reference the same foreign key.

Is there a simple way to make it so that if there are 1 or more entries with the same foreign key that a value of "true" (or some other value) is returned rather than n seperate rows?

eg.

I want this:

```
id |  Date
1  |  true
2  |  NULL
```

instead of this (what is happening now):

```
id |  Date
1  |  feb 4
1  |  feb 5
1  |  feb 6
2  |  NULL
2  |  feb 5
```

if there are no values I just want a null for the date

EDIT
I forgot about the case where you have both values and nulls for the same primary key (id# 2).  In this case I need to be able to return Null.  If there are any nulls then it should return a null.
EDIT

I've tried playing around with a group by function but can't get anything close to what I'm trying to accomplish

This is a simplified version of my query as it is already, don't want to confuse the issue with the extra columns.

```
SELECT distinct job, DATE_FORMAT( scan_date, '%M %e, %Y, %l:%i%p' ) AS Scanning
FROM Scan, job
WHERE Scan.job_job = job
```

Comment: So you want to return `true` if there is a value for date and `null` if there is none?

Comment: correct, there is also the case however where if there is a date that is null, and a date that is defined for the same id, then I want it to return null as well. (see id #2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if any scan record exists rather than joining to the Scan table directly:

```
SELECT distinct job, exists(select 1 from Scan where Scan.job_job = job) AS Scanning
FROM job;
```

This will return 1 if a Scan record exists, 0 if not. If you really want to use "true" and NULL, you can wrap the exists in IF().

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this to account for my second case.  Ending up using this: if(exists(select site from Scan where (site='' OR site=NULL) and Scan.job_job = job.job), NULL, true) as Scanning,

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but give this a try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT j.job, CASE WHEN scan_date IS NULL THEN null 
                            ELSE 'true'
                       END
FROM Scan, job
WHERE Scan.job_job = job
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, from what I can tell this seems to only return values of 1 in the date field

Comment: One man's `1` is another man's `true`.  I went ahead and changed it to the string `true` so it should produce the desired results now.

Answer (score 0):

To return true or null, you can use the CASE WHEN statement in the select clause. See - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT job, COUNT(scan_date) != 0 AS Scanning
  FROM job
  LEFT JOIN scan ON job_job = job
  GROUP BY job
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
SELECT j.job, IF(COUNT(s.scan_date) > 0, 'true', NULL) AS Scanning
FROM job j
LEFT JOIN Scan s
  ON j.job = s.job_job
GROUP BY j.job
```

Comment: this base query gives me a correct true and NULL for my date field - working to see if I can incorporate it into my larger query correctly